# is there a way to create a 'Generic' CSV file format with FileHelpers

Tags: filehelpers

I would like to use FileHelpers to read a CSV file with an unknown file layout (except that it is comma delimited).  I would basically like to have a string[] for row where each item is a field.  Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it ! Use a smart format detector : https://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/SmartFormatDetector/

Comment: You certainly can answer your own question, but answers that are links are frowned upon. Please put the detail in the answer and only link to provide supporting evidence.